# How to compare negative numbers to positive numbers in MIPs assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

Is this code here comparing 10 > -9, I'm new to mips so I'm not sure how negative numbers would be handled when branching

```
main:
     add $t0, $zero, 10
     bge $t0, -9, label
```

Comment: `bge` is a signed compare.  `bgeu` is unsigned.

Comment: wouldn't we want it to be signed to compare negative numbers

Comment: Yes, that's why `bge` is the instruction you want.

Comment: lol for some reason it only works with bgeu, it branches into the label with bge, but it doesn't with bgeu

Comment: `10 > -9` is true for signed, false for unsigned.  Your idea of "works" is apparently based on getting the logic backwards.  But you didn't show any other code so we can't tell you what's wrong with your program.  The `bge` should be taken in this case, `bgeu` would be not-taken (fall through).

Comment: ahh ur right i was thinking backwards thank you